# Difficulty understanding some phrases in a paragraph

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

Can anyone help me explain the total meaning of this paragraph?

> Exercise 3.43: Suppose that the balances in three accounts start out
>   as $10, $20, and $30, and that multiple processes run, exchanging the
>   balances in the accounts. Argue that if the processes are run
>   sequentially, after any number of concurrent exchanges, the account
>   balances should be $10, $20, and $30 in some order. Draw a timing
>   diagram like the one in Figure 3.29 to show how this condition can be
>   violated if the exchanges are implemented using the first version of
>   the account-exchange program in this section. On the other hand, argue
>   that even with this exchange program, the sum of the balances in the
>   accounts will be preserved. Draw a timing diagram to show how even
>   this condition would be violated if we did not serialize the
>   transactions on individual accounts.

[Source](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/3_002e4.xhtml)

There are many things I do not understand in this paragraph. My questions are:

- "if the processes are run sequentially, after any number of concurrent exchanges," - as I understand it, the word "sequential" and "concurrent" mean contradictory things. As far as I know "sequential" means one at a time and "concurrent" means occuring at the same time or simultaneous. I translated this as: if the processes are run one at a time, after any number of simultaneous exchanges. How could simultaneous things be happening if things happen one at a time? I am totally confused.
- "the account balances should be $10, $20, and $30 in some order." - Does this mean we should find out all orders of exchanges that lead to three banks having $10, $20 and $30 respectively?
- "the sum of the balances in the accounts will be preserved." - This is a little clearer. Does preserved means "the account balances should be $10, $20, and $30 in some order." just like what is said previously?

Can anyone totally explain things I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is not a single question; the individual questions do not look fully acceptable on ELU either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Argue that if the processes are run sequentially, after any number of
>   concurrent exchanges, the account balances should be $10, $20, and $30
>   in some order.

I believe this means that the requests are happening concurrently, but the program is queuing them up and processing them sequentially.

> "the account balances should be $10, $20, and $30 in some order." -
>   Does this mean we should find out all orders of exchanges that lead to
>   three banks having $10, $20 and $30 respectively?

No, they are asking for a logical argument that the values $10, $20, $30 must  exist in the accounts in some order after the process completes.

Suppose the accounts are named A, B, and C.  Let's say A has $10 and B has $20.  After an exchange A would have $20 and B would have $10.  Since all exchanges happen in a sequential way, they want you to argue that the amounts are always preserved.

> On the other hand, argue that even with this exchange program, the sum
>   of the balances in the accounts will be preserved.

I believe they are now referring to concurrency as defined in the first version of the program.  They are asking for a proof that the sum of A, B, C would be 10 + 20 + 30 = 60.

This is difficult to answer without understanding the problem fully.  In particular, we would need to understand the concurrent nature of read / writes in the problem.

Furthermore, it seems the first version of the program already has some serialization.  They want a proof that if it were removed, then A + B + C = 60 would also be violated.